# Gluster replication / propagation to multiple remote servers

Tags: glusterfs, file-replication-services

I'm new to the concept of Gluster, and I think I'm missing some key knowledge from Gluster documentation.

In my company, there are 10 application servers each with their own storage, and the current workflow for updating the source code, is to copy manually to each servers. This is tedious especially if there was any bug that got through testing.

I wanted to just copy to one server/gluster node then have it propagate to all the other application servers. I have googled and studied on Gluster, but the documentation says not to have too many replicas [The link to the dos and don'ts](https://www.gluster.org/glusterfs-replication-dos-and-donts/)

I was just wondering, what's the best way to proceed if I'm going to have to use Gluster?

Thanks in advance, appreciate your kind response.